# Adding element to antd Dropdown overlay property results in React single child error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Stripped down code:

```
const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>
      1st menu item
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

export const QBDropdown: React.FC = () => 
  <div>
    <Dropdown overlay={menu} />
  </div>
```

When attempting to populate the overlay property in the antd dropdown, the following error always occurs:

> Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element
> child.

It does so seemingly regardless of what I populate it with. A single `<div></div>` or `<></>` produces the same error. What's going on here?

Comment: maybe you missed parentheses around QBDropdown component implicit return... export const QBDropdown: React.FC = () => (
  <div>
    <Dropdown overlay={menu} />
  </div>
)

Comment: Sadly not. I tried bracketing the arrow function body and the same thing happens.

Comment: Looks like correct. Try adding more info. Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hooks-5zjdy?file=/index.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dropdown menu must have a child. which can be verified using `React.Children.only`

```
 <div>
    <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
      <button>Something to trigger the menu</button>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/bf72f5538a9a788639bd4b56a1ccc9f86ea453c3/components/dropdown/dropdown.tsx#L144

Comment: This doesn't work for me but I'll take a look at the childrenonly function, see if it gives me more debug info. tnx

Comment: I've taken a look at the function you mentioned; logging the result to the console yields a React symbol of some sort, which I can add to the question if you like. This object has a props property, containing a children property, the value of which is an array with two values when the button is included as shown. Without the button, there is one value the array that corresponds to the 'children' key, but the same error occurs.

Comment: check this sandbox. the issue might be that you added a text node instead of a child https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cohen-tw3eg?file=/index.js

Comment: The code is now working in a new browser window. Appears there were caching issues or similar....

Comment: it works.it saved me.

Answer (score 1):

If you face that issue after updating to `antd v5`, it might be related to the new flow for the Dropdown `menu`(`overlay` old way).

Console warning:

> Warning: [antd: Menu] `children` will be removed in next major version. Please use `items` instead.

deprecated way:

```
const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item key='1' onClick={() => handleDuplicate(record.id)}>
      Duplicate
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
<Dropdown.Button href={url} overlay={menu}>
  Edit
</Dropdown.Button>
```

new:

```
const items = [{
  label: 'Duplicate',
  key: '1',
  onClick: () => handleDuplicate(record.id),
}];
const menuProps = {
  items,
};
<Dropdown.Button href={url} menu={menuProps}>
  Edit
</Dropdown.Button>
```

Comment: What if I want to use custom content in dropdown overlay instead of menu items? Old component allowed to use `ReactElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Dropdown like this in `antd v5`

```
const profileItems = [
{
  key: "1",
  label: (
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      1st menu item
    </a>
  ),
},
{
  key: "2",
  label: (
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      2nd menu item (disabled)
    </a>
  ),
  icon: <LoginOutlined />,
  disabled: true,
},
{
  key: "3",
  label: (
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      3rd menu item (disabled)
    </a>
  ),
  disabled: true,
},
{
  key: "4",
  danger: true,
  label: "a danger item",
}]

<Dropdown menu={{ items: profileItems }}>
   <div className="logo">
      <LoginOutlined />
      <div>Profile</div>
   </div>
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

it means ur Dropdown component must have one child

```
import { Menu, Dropdown, Button } from "antd";
const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>
      1st menu item
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

export const QBDropdown: React.FC = () => 
  <div>
    <Dropdown overlay={menu} placement="dropDown">
     <Button>dropdown</Button>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-vaughan-b950k?file=/src/App.js check this it works fine